# Angular and youtube iframe issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, youtube

I'm trying to add a youtube video to my app, but angular removes the iframe code and does not appear, I'm using this

```
<div class="content-read" ng-bind-html="data.content"> </ div>
```

try using ng-bind-html-unsafe, but I think this was removed from the current version of angularjs

I'm using angular 1.2.3

I have also this

```
app.config(['$sceDelegateProvider', function($sceDelegateProvider) {
     $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
        'self',
        'http://www.youtube.com/**',
    ]);

}]);
```

Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

the best solution I found, is to create a directive that meets the function of ng-bind-html-unsafe

```
app.directive('ngBindHtmlUnsafe', ['$sce', function($sce){
return {
    scope: {
        ngBindHtmlUnsafe: '=',
    },
    template: "<div ng-bind-html='trustedHtml'></div>",
    link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
        $scope.updateView = function() {
            $scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.ngBindHtmlUnsafe);
        }

        $scope.$watch('ngBindHtmlUnsafe', function(newVal, oldVal) {
            $scope.updateView(newVal);
        });
    }
};
}]);
```